# How to use np.gradient on multidimensional data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numerical-methods, differentiation

There exist a lot of questions on this, but I can't find one that describes this particular use case.

I have a matrix `P`, which gives a scalar value in a 3D field of size `(dx,dy,dz)=(360, 720, 30)` over `41` timesteps. That is,

```
>>> np.shape(P)
(41, 30, 360, 720)
```

As is seen, the z-index (we'll call it the "vertical") is the second dimension.

I want to calculate *dP/dz* for this field.

However, the spacing in z is not uniform in *any* of the three spatial dimensions, *and* is time-variate (simply imagine that each grid point is allowed to float around per-timestep). That is, there is an associated matrix giving the vertical coordinates of *each grid point* in the 3D space, `Z3`, where

```
>>> np.shape(Z3)
(41, 30, 360, 720)
```

How do I then use `np.gradient()` to obtain *P'(t, x, y)*, where *P'=dP/dz*?

When I try differentiating along axis 1, I get:

```
>>> np.gradient(P, Z3, axis=1)
*** ValueError: distances must be either scalars or 1d
```

This error is very opaque, since it contradicts the documentation, which describes the ability to pass *N* dimensional spacings. However, this does work:

```
>>> np.gradient(P[0,:,0,0], Z3[0,:,0,0])
```

This essentially gives me *dP/dz* in one "vertical column" of the field, i.e. the derivative of `P` at the origin at time=0, *P'(0,0,0)*. Consider the horrifically slow code:

```
dpdz = np.zeros(np.shape(P))

for i in range(np.shape(P)[0]):
    for j in range(np.shape(P)[2]):
        for k in range(np.shape(P)[3]):
            dpdz[i,:,j,k] = np.gradient(P[i,:,j,k], Z3[i,:,j,k])
```

This is exactly the result that I would expect `np.gradient(P, Z3, axis=1)` to give. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: np.gradient is not the right function for this data unless you resample it to an equal grid

Comment: @MadPhysicist So the function is designed to handle non-uniform grid spacings, but only if each one of those spacings is uniform with respect to all of the other dimensions of the grid? Can you suggest an alternative?

Comment: Resampling to a common grid is one option

Comment: @MadPhysicist In this case it would be a matter of interpolation (in the second, or z,  dimension), not resampling. Z3 would then be 1d. Would adding this interpolation step be the most efficient option? Or is there another more complex differentiation scheme that I could import?

Comment: I honestly don't know. I'd probably look into interpolation (thanks for that catch) because it's more efficient of my time than anything.